# custom conditions in htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to create an htaccess file, that when a person is ANY file access (like this "home / conf.php") or url (like this "/ home / asdasda") is redirected to / index.php, with the exception of a folder called "/ uploads".

That's because I do not want anyone to have access to any file from my site, and that all possible paths are taken to index.php.

I've tried everything and there's always something that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/index\.php|/uploads/) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Wow, it's working!
exactly how I want it.
Thank you!